# Can't Figure Out How To Implement HERE sdk for Flutter

Tags: flutter, here-api

So I've been trying to use the HERE sdk for flutter, but whenever I add the unzipped file to the plugins folder and add it to the pubsec.yaml it gives me this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTZUx.png)

Here is my project directory for the plugins folder:
[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh12j.png)

I feel like I'm doing something really dumb, but I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the folder structure is not as expected. If you follow the [quick start guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-explore/4.3.0.0/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html#try-the-example-apps), you need to identify the plugin folder:

1. Unzip the downloaded HERE SDK for Flutter package. This folder contains various files including this documentation.
2. Inside you will find a TAR file that contains the HERE SDK for Flutter plugin.
3. Now unzip the plugin, then rename the folder to 'here_sdk' and place it to the `plugins` folder inside the example app's directory.

So, you need to unzip the package and then again inside the package you need to unzip the TAR (containing the plugin).

Comment: I used the tar file which is a .gz file, but now it is saying that it has to refer to a directory and not a file when I run flutter pub get

Comment: Also, the tar file was already unzipped when I extracted the original sdk package, so I am not able to unzip the plugin.

Comment: Could post the steps with pictures? That would be really helpful.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out, I just had to get 7 Zip to extract the .tar.gz file, thanks for your help